# No Flash Player in Chromium on OSX

Tags: macos, flash, chromium

Few days ago I switched from Firefox to Chromium. I really liked it, but it has one minor issue. I can't make it run flash.

I followed [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-chromium.html#id_29382) article, but there is no Flash Player entry on my about:plugins page.

In other browsers (Safari, Firefox, Opera) Flash Player works correctly. I am using OS X 10.10.

Comment: Did you install the Flash Player yet? If so, what method did you use?  Also, which version/build of Chromium are you using?

Comment: Yes, I did. I downloaded and installed Flash Player from Adobe website, version marked as made for Opera and Chromium (Pepper Flash Player). I am using version 42.0.2301.0 (64-bit).

Comment: If you want/need Flash, why not just use Chrome instead of Chromium?  Not like the Flash embedded in Chrome is a heavy lift or anything.  Google also saves you the effort of updating since they handle all that.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I found Chromium to be a bit faster than Chrome. But I can give it a second try.

Comment: @killermist There's usually a pretty specific reason people use Chromium over Chrome. That reason is usually security/privacy/less bloat. I really don't think an 'easy flash install' is worth throwing all that away.

Answer (score 4):

try chrome://flags/
and Enable NPAPI

Comment: Not sure about chromium, but this is the fix for the latest (Chrome 42). It requires a restart. Also just a reminder I believe Sept 2015 there will no longer be this workaround. Chrome will be done supporting flash.

Comment: After a lot of searches, this is the first time I've seen this flag, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

NPAPI will be finished soon.
Here is just a knowledge about how to load PPAPI Flash to Chromium for osx.

INSTALL newest flash player (now 18.0.0.209) from adobe.
https://get.adobe.com/jp/flashplayer/otherversions/
choose osx and chromium, download, and install.

Chromium can't load it as default.
SO you have to launch Chromium by Terminal with optional command.
Everytime you launch Terminal.app then type following text and hit enter key.

/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium --ppapi-flash-path=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/PepperFlashPlayer/PepperFlashPlayer.plugin --ppapi-flash-version=18.0.0.209

Your chromium will load newest ppapi flash on OSX level.
To confirm, Go to following url by chromium.
chrome://plugins

I see it is crazy.
I wish it should be loaded automatically as default.

Comment: After completely shutting down Chromium, this worked for me.

Comment: It works only when I running Chromium from the console. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Flash Player on Chromium on a Mac system is easy, follow these instructions:

1. On chromium, open a new tab and navigate to `chrome://flags`, goto NPAPI section and enable it.
2. Download Flash NPAPI

   - [Web page](https://helpx.adobe.com/fr/flash-player/kb/installation-problems-flash-player-mac.html)
   - [direct link](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/latest/help/install_flash_player_osx.dmg)
3. Install Flash player
4. On Chromium open a new tab and navigate to `chrome://plugins`, goto the Flash player section, (normally it is enabled - if not, enable it) and tick 'Always allowed to run'
5. Open a new tab to a web page using Flash and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

The way I ended up "fixing" it on my installation was by creating a small executable replacing the default in Contents/MacOS. I renamed the Chromium binary Chromium_ and complied the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    system("/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium_ --ppapi-flash-path=/Library/Internet\\ Plug-Ins/PepperFlashPlayer/PepperFlashPlayer.plugin/Contents/MacOS/PepperFlashPlayer --ppapi-flash-version=19.0.0.226");
    return 0;
}
```

By compiling the code and naming it Chromium, I now simply click the regular Chromium icon to launch the browser with flash. While it works, the executable doesn't persist after updating Chromium via Chromatic. Additionally, every time you update the PPAPI plug, you need to edit and recompile the code. To get around it, I threw together the following on GitHub: https://github.com/andersensam/enableChromiumFlash. It prompts for a version of the PPAPI plugin desired and replaces the binary in Contents/MacOS. Hope this helps!

Comment: Elegant solution ! +1

Comment: +1 Still works on Mac OS X. Using Chromium Version 51.0.2704.0 (64-bit) for development purposes.

I did have to change the IO lib from `#include <iostream>` to `#include <stdio.h>`. But otherwise works perfectly!

Compiled with `/usr/bin/cc Chromium.c -o Chromium`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to install it, according to Adobe's [Flash Player Help / Use Flash Player with Chromium](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-chromium.html) page:

> To view content with Flash Player in the Chromium open source web browser, install the Flash Player plug-in at [get.adobe.com/flashplayer](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).
>
> Note: Unlike Chromium, the similar Google Chrome browser includes Adobe Flash Player built-in.

---

Or, how about [Use Pepper Flash Player From Google Chrome In Chromium Browser [How To]](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/how-to-make-chromium-use-flash-player.html) (linux)?

1. Download and install Google Chrome.
2. Now, to launch Chromium browser with the Adobe Flash Player version bundled with Google Chrome, use the following command:

   ```
   chromium-browser --ppapi-flash-path=/opt/google/chrome*/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=11.3.31.323
   ```
3. Try it out and if Adobe Flash Player that comes bundled with Google Chrome is working fine for you in Chromium, let's make it permanent so you don't have to use any command line parameters in the future.

   For this, you need to open the /etc/chromium-browser/default file as root with a text editor:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/chromium-browser/default
   ```

   And replace CHROMIUM_FLAGS="" with the following:

   ```
   CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--ppapi-flash-path=/opt/google/chrome*/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=$PEPPER_FLASH_VERSION"
   ```

   This will automatically get the Flash Player version from the Google Chrome manifest file once you log out and log back in.

Comment: You linked the same article as I did in main post. As I said, I followed it, including downloading and installing Flash Player.

Comment: Didn't follow your link, sounded like a long/old "article" from some blog or someplace. You didn't say you already installed the Flash Player from Adobe, didn't think the link I/we found was even called an "article", just checked for how to do it "from the horse's mouth" (Adobe). Yours now sounds more like a troubleshooting/bug issue

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but some might still find this useful. Following the direction of user470821, I modified the chromium app, by navigating to `Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS` and changing the `Chromium` file to `_Chromium` then I created a simple shell script with the name `Chromium` in the same directory:

```
/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/_Chromium \
--ppapi-flash-path=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/PepperFlashPlayer/PepperFlashPlayer.plugin \
--ppapi-flash-version=25.0.0.148
```

Finally, just make sure to run the following command once the shell script is written:

```
chmod +x /Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium
```

Now I can open the chromium app without using the terminal and the whole thing just works.